# How to setting multilingual plone site with subdomain such as en.hostname.com and de.hostname.com

Tags: internationalization, plone, multilingual

as title, 
I wish my plone site can use subdomain in each language, like
http://en.myhost.com
but I check the "use subdomain" option, but not work!
these url still have language postfix, like
http://www.myhost.com/en
How can I do ?

Comment: Note: My plone site environment is plone 4.3.2 with plone.app.multilingual 2.0.0